# How to override attribute in Base class Python3 , so that subsequent operations remains same verywhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have a use case, where I have to override one attribute in base class **init**, but the operations after that ( by making use of that attribute ) remains the same.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, record_file = None):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        if self.record_file:
            self.contents = json.load(open(self.record_file))
        else:
            self.contents = {'person_specific_details': details}
            
        #### Do some operations with self.contents

class Teenager(Person):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        # If self.record_file is None:
        # self.contents = new for Teenager
        self.contents = {'teenager_specific_details': teenager_details}
        # But further operations remains the same (#### Do some operations with self.contents)
t = Teenager(phone='xxxxxx', name='XXXXXXX')
```

I am not able to acheive it properly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you want to change an intermediate value in the `Person.__init__`, which won't work. But you could create an optional argument for the `contents` and just use that instead of the default one.
Like this:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, record_file=None, contents=None):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        if record_file:
            with open(record_file) as fp:
                self.contents = json.load(fp)
        else:
            if contents:  # can be utilized by other subclasses
                self.contents = contents
            else:
                self.contents = {"person_specific_details": details}

        #### Do some operations with self.contents


class Teenager(Person):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        contents = {"teenager_specific_details": teenager_details}
        super().__init__(contents=contents, **kwargs)


t = Teenager(phone="xxxxxx", name="XXXXXXX")
```

This way you can pass the `Teenager` specific contents to the base initializaion, and it can proceed further with that one.

Comment: I was thinking same, but just wanted to know, whether it was possible. Very precise and short answer. Thank you.